# How to implement a Selenium code in cloud tool like crossbrowser testing?

Tags: selenium-ide

We are doing a Selenium based web application testing. We have a requirement to test the application in different browsers.

The requirement is also use browsers from cloud applications like crossbrowser testing.(https://crossbrowsertesting.com/). We are not getting enough idea how to implement and execute our script within crossbrowser tool.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're stuck on, and it seems like this question could do with some more research on your side. Selenium works with at least Chrome and Firefox, have you got either working? Have you started an instance of Selenium server? What language do you want to use to drive your tests? Have you selected a test framework?